# A Polar Coordinates Computation

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations

I'm looking at the following computation:
[image]
Here: $u_k = u(x_0 + \rho_k x)/\rho_k$

I'm having trouble understanding the change of variables.

1. For the first integral if I consider $x' \mapsto x_0 + \rho_k x$ then $dx'/\rho_k^n = dx$ -- there's an extra factor of $\rho_k$ in the denominator of the first integral though.
2. For the second integral if I set $r' \mapsto \rho_k r$ then the conversion works because there's a hidden factor of $r^{n-1}$ in the $d\mathcal{H}^{n-1}$, is that correct?
3. $Q^2$ should be evaluated at $0$ in the second integral, instead of $x_0$, is that correct?

Comment: Whose PDE book/paper is this from? It may be easier to comprehend if the whole calculation is seen.

Comment: It's from a paper: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02921941 (bottom of pg 5)

Comment: For (1), isn't the factor of $\rho_k^n$ canceled with the one in front of the integral?

Comment: ya -- but in the first integral in the next equality, $\nabla u \mapsto \nabla u_k $. There's an extra factor of $\rho_k$ downstairs of $u_k$ -- I'm not sure where its coming from.

Comment: For (3), $Q^2(x_0)$ is a constant, so it remains the same when doing change of variables.

Comment: You have a typo in your definition of $u_k$.

Comment: If you look at the definition of $u_k$, when taking the gradient, the $\rho_k$ will cancel because there is a $\rho_k$ in the denominator.

Comment: I am having trouble seeing this -- perhaps you can be a little more explicit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (1), the factor of $\rho_k^n$ in the new differential cancels out with the one in front of the integral.

For (3), $Q_2(x_0)$  is a constant, so it remains the same when doing the change of variables.

For (2), note that you also have $\rho_k$ in the denominator in the definition of $u_k$. Think about a 1D example: $v(x)=\frac{u(2x)}{2}$. You have
$$
|v'(x)|=|u'(2x)|
$$
so you have no extra factor of $2$ when you take the gradient.

---

Lebesgue integral is shift-invariant. So without loss generality, we can assume that $x_0=0$. Now for any $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ you have by direct calculation
$$
\nabla u_k(x)=\nabla u(\rho x)\,.
$$
For simplicity, just write $\rho$ for $\rho_k$.
Now you have

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{\rho^nR^n}\int_{B_{\rho R}(0)}|\nabla u(x)|^2dx
&=\frac{1}{\rho^nR^n}\int_{B_R(0)}|\nabla u(\frac{y}{\rho})|^2\rho^ndy
&(y=\rho x,\quad dy=\rho^n dx)\\
&=\frac{1}{\rho^nR^n}\int_{B_R(0)}|\nabla u_k(y)|^2\rho^ndy
\end{align}

If you are confused with notations, it is very useful to calculate a 1D example.